# How do i fill a list with objects that are passed to a class(2nd class) from another class(3rd class)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
public class E
{
    public static List<Tranzactie> tranzactie = new List<Tranzactie>();
}

public class Tranzactie
{
    public string name;
    public string contract;
}


static void main()
{
    where i have a method with a loop that parses a.txt file
         and passes extracted values to Tranzactie
}
```

In class E there is a list i want to populate with values extracted from parsing a txtfile in Main. The data collected in Main fills fields from class Tranzactie.

How do i put the values passed to "Tranzactie" into the list found in class E?

Comment: `E.transactie.Add(parsedTranzactie);`

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Well, somewhere in your loop, you'll need to:

- instantiate a `new Tranzactie` object
- populate the `name` and `contract` fields
- add this object to your `List<Tranzactie>`

So, here's the code to do just that part:

```cs
// assuming you have variables "name" and "contract" that hold necessary data
var tranzactie = new Tranzactie() 
{
   name = name, 
   contract = contract
};
E.tranzactie.Add(tranzactie);
```

As an aside, I would rename the `List<Tranzactie>` in `class E` to `tranzactii`, because it represents *multiple transactions* - a collection - so plural form of the word is typically preferred.